# Run databricks jar task

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub, databricks-workflows

To install a jar library on a job cluster, I try to use the jar task, where I select the maven library, but I can not find the main class of the library. does anyone know what the main class for com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22
is?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22` is a library for consumption of data from Azure Event Hubs - it's doesn't have `main` entry point and couldn't be used as Databricks Job task.  You need to write a code that will use that library, then compile it and use produced `.jar` file for your task.